# CCD/IMG/SUB conversion to CUE/BIN

Tags: format-conversion

I have lots of image (Sega Saturn Roms) in ccd/img/sub format.
In order to play them in emulator I need them in cue/bin format.
I can't find any fast way to convert them.
I could use IAT to convert them in iso format, but i don't know how to revert iso images in cue/bin format.
Of course I need a CLI tool, in order to process lots of subdirectory which contains the files.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this GNU linux utility: [GNU ccd2cue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ccd2cue/manual/ccd2cue.html#Release).